# serilog 1.5.1 missing CloseAndFlush()

Tags: c#, serilog

I am using serilog v1.5.1 (due to compatibility with .NET 4.0) and there is no CloseAndFlush() function.  What is the alternative?  It is generating the log file but not writing to it.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .WriteTo.File($"logs/log{timestamp}.txt", outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
            .CreateLogger();

        Log.Information("test!!");
        Log.Logger.Information("Hello!");
```

Comment: `CloseAndFlush` is only a `static` member of the `static class Log` type, it isn't a member of `Logger`. It's always been like that. That's because `Log.CloseAndFlush()` should only be invoked when the host process is terminating, and because instances of Serilog's `ILogger` aren't `IDisposable`. (also not to be confused with `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`. Personally I recommend using Serilog _only_ a backend for `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` ("MEL") and only use MEL inside application code.

Comment: I was able to call Log.CloseAndFlush(); in the Main method of another project but not the current one I'm doing and the only difference is the Serilog version I'm using.

Comment: Hang on, I just noticed that Serilog 1.5.1 is **ancient** ([vintage 2015](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog/1.5.1)) - you should be using Serilog 2.10 or later now.